# Why is the value for android:background still being used after a switch to a new theme

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have this in my Style.xml within my Xamarin.Android application:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Splash styles -->
    <style name="Theme.Splash" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/splash_drawable</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- window:background is not set here, but even if it set (to say, @null for eg), there is no change. The value from Theme.Splash is preserved. -->
        ....
```

My MainActivity.cs looks like this:

```
[Activity(
    Label = "My app",
    Icon = "@drawable/icon",
    Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash",
    MainLauncher = true,
    LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Locale | ConfigChanges.LayoutDirection,
    ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait
    )
]

public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        // Changing to App theme since we are in OnCreate and we are ready to
        // "hide" the splash.
        // But the android:background property value from Theme.Splash remains.
        base.Window.RequestFeature(WindowFeatures.ActionBar);
        base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.AppTheme);
        ...
```

How can I remove whatever was set for `android:background`? It's causing major problems since it's overlapping all my views when the app has finished loading.

NOTE: I can't use `android:windowBackground` in `Theme.Splash` instead, as that causes my custom splash page to be shifted below the status bar.

Comment: I made a weird as f&$k observation, that I can't seem to find any documentation for. If I change the name of the style from `AppTheme` to `Theme.AppTheme` and change the call in `OnCreate` from `base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.AppTheme);` to `base.SetTheme(Resource.Style.Theme_AppTheme);`, I get some changed behaviour...like some of the properties in the style are being recognised, but not all.

Comment: Why do you even have the  `Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash",` in your activity header anyway? This should only be there in your Splash theme don't you think!?

Comment: @G.hakim Do you mean it should be an attribute of my splash activity? If so, then yes, I agree. However this is how it’s currently setup; I could try refactoring.

Comment: It should only be in your Splash's Activity Attribute not on your MainActivity, MainActivity should only have your App's global theme

Comment: @G.hakim I refactored to use a dedicated SplashActivity from which I start the MainActivity, and everything now works as I expect. if you'd like to turn your comment into an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Just override `android:background` inside AppTheme.

Comment: Have a look at the comment I've added to the `AppTheme` style. It makes no difference, so this does not work.

Comment: Please also see the comment I added to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you "can't use android:windowBackground in Theme.Splash instead, as that causes my custom splash page to be shifted below the status bar". Try adding:

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_drawable</item>
```

that should resolve that. Make sure that your drawable is responsive so you don't have issues with different screen sizes and configurations.

********************* Update *********************

Try setting the splash theme in manifest.xml in the application tag and using a splashscreen activity that  then launches the MainActivity with the App theme. You can do app initialization in the splash activity (remember that synchronous app initialization should be limited to those things that have to be done before the user can access the UI, everything else should be done asynchronously and trigger change in the UI via an event). We almost exclusively use this approach as we generally have an authentication process which we do here, and add messages and progress bars over the splash, such as "Initializing" or "Attempting to Authenticate" to keep the user engaged.

Here’s an example of what I mean:

In the manifest.xm. include:

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/AppDark.Fullscreen.Splash" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_app_launcher">
…..
<application>
```

In Styles .xml include:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppDark">
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
  <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
  <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
  <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
  <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/app_background</item>
  <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
<style name="AppLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
  <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/app_background</item>
</style>
<style name="AppLight.Fullscreen">
  <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
<style name="AppLight.Fullscreen.Splash">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/responsive_splashscreen</item>
</style>
```

Then for the activities:

```
[Activity(
Label = "@string/app_name", 
MainLauncher = true, 
Exported = true, 
LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask,
ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Locale | ConfigChanges.LayoutDirection,
ScreenOrientation = global::Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]

public class SplashActivity : BaseActivity
{
…….

[Activity(
Label = "@string/app_name", 
Theme = "@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Locale | ConfigChanges.LayoutDirection,
ScreenOrientation = global::Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait,
WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize)]

public class MainActivity : BaseActivity
{
…….
```

Comment: Did try this, did not work for me. I think it's most likely due to bizarre behaviour caused as a result of the MainActivity launching with the Splash theme and then later changing the theme.

Comment: Remember that if you change the Theme of an activity programmatically it will not take effect until the Activity runs OnResume, so you have to leave and return to the activity (or close/start, pause/resume etc. it) for the change to take effect, however changes to the Window property will take effect within the current lifecycle state.

Comment: See my update for an approach that may work for you.